# Joining 3 Tables on mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Good Day.

I know this question is already asked but I have a hard time implementing my problem.

I want to **Join** 3 tables. Here is how my tables look like:

```
Order_Header(Order_Header_ID{PK}, Order_Date, Order_Time, Order_Complete)
Order_Line(Order_Line_ID{PK}, Product_ID{FK}, Order_Header_ID{FK},Quantity)
Products(Product_ID{PK}, Description, Cost)
```

I Want to JOIN the three tables so that in one table it displays **Order_Header_ID, Quantity and Description** out of the three tables WHERE **Order_Complete** = 'YES'.
I have the following SQL that displays all the information but do not join them.

```
SELECT
    Order_Header.Order_Header_ID,
    Products.Description,
    Order_Line.Quantity
FROM Order_Header, Products, Order_Line
WHERE Order_Complete = 'yes'
```

The idea is that it list a Order_Header_ID once with the corresponding Description and Quantity only once.

Thank you in advance

Comment: " I have the following SQL that displays all the information but do not join them." `FROM Order_Header, Products, Order_Line
WHERE Order_Complete = 'yes'`  actually you are using a old implicit CROSS JOIN syntax here

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "Never use commas in the `FROM` clause" sounds too strong. Inner joining tables by putting them in `FROM` clause makes sense. The only problem is that `WHERE` clause must contain proper join condition(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is missing join conditions.  Also, it is preferable to use an explicit join syntax.  Correcting for both of these things we can write the following query:

```
SELECT
    oh.Order_Header_ID,
    p.Description,
    ol.Quantity
FROM Order_Header oh
INNER JOIN Order_Line ol
    ON oh.Order_Header_ID = ol.Order_Header_ID
INNER JOIN Products p
    ON ol.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
WHERE
    oh.Order_Complete = 'yes'
```